# CI of PPV and NPV using pROC

Tags: r, roc, proc-r-package

I've been using the `pROC` package in R to generate bootstrapped confidence intervals for SP and SN values corresponding to specific thresholds. However, I've been unable to find a way to generate CI's for PPV and NPV values. Does such a function exist inside `pROC`?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you at least posted a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data that calculates PPV and NPV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ci.coords`. Type `?ci.coords` for more information.